# why $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{z}^{z+h} f( \xi) d\xi \to f(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I have some  doubt in Morera 's theorem, my  doubt is given marked in red box
[image]

**My attempt** : Here it given that $$\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h} = \frac{1}{h} \int_{z}^{z+h} f( \xi) d\xi \to f(z)$$

If $h \to 0$  Then $$\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{z}^{z+h} f( \xi) d\xi = \infty$$

since $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}= \infty$

**My doubt** : why $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{z}^{z+h} f( \xi) d\xi \to f(z)$?

Comment: Both $h$ and the integral tends to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because\begin{align}\require{cancel}\left|\frac1h\int_z^{z+h}f(\xi)\,\mathrm d\xi-f(z)\right|&=\left|\frac{\int_z^{z+h}f(\xi)-f(z)\,\mathrm d\xi}h\right|\\&\leqslant\frac{\cancel h\max_{\xi\in[z,z+h]}|f(\xi)-f(z)|}{\cancel h}\\&\to0,\end{align}when $h\to0$, since $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $\int_{z}^{z}f(\xi)d\xi=0.$

Now since $f$ is continuous on the open set D using L'Hôpital's rule (and Leibniz integral rule for $\mathbb C$) we have:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{z}^{z+h}f(\xi)d\xi}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z+h)}{1}\rightarrow f(z).$$

Comment: Im getting confuse @Ares i think $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{z}^{z+h}f(\xi)d\xi}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z+h)\frac{d(z+h)}{dz}-z\frac{dz}{dz}}{1}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{1}=0.$$ How did u derive $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{z}^{z+h}f(\xi)d\xi}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z+h)}{1}?$$

Comment: The derivative is taken wrt to $h$. So $\frac{d}{dh}(z+h)=1$ and $\frac{dz}{dh}=0.$

Comment: okss  got it thanks u @Ares

Comment: You're welcome! But I think José's answer is better.